# node js - Download pdf via HTTP post and upload to azure blob storage

Tags: node.js, azure-blob-storage

I've an online API that returns PDF files via HTTP post requests.
Once I get back the response with the file I would like to upload the file in an azure blob storage.

I've tried everything on here and I'm unable to get it work.

Where I'm now:

```
  async function getPDFfile(idSession) {
        let connectionJson = {
            "DeviceId": "device-id",
            "SessionId": idSession,
            "ContainerId": contaierID
        }

        axios({
            url: 'https://URL/exportPDF/',
            method: 'POST',
            Headers: connectionJson,
            responseType: "arraybuffer",
            responseEncoding: "binary"
        }).then((response) => {
            console.log(response.data)
         });
```

If I print this I will get a <Buffer  but as I cannot really see what's Inside I cannot use it.

If I use axios without params:

```
        const response = await axios
            .post('https://URL/exportPDF/', connectionJson)

        return response.data
```

Here I get loads of unicode characers with some information, I've tried to upload this but the PDF file is only few bytes and obviously does not work.

I've tried to get the response as blob but same, was not working.

Could you please help me with figure this out?

this should run on azure function. Thank you for your time.

---- Edit

While the first method doesn't return anything in the data, the second without parameters returns a very long string with:

```
%PDF-1.4
%´┐¢´┐¢´┐¢´┐¢
1 0 obj
<<
/CreationDate(D:20220423222622+01'00')
/Creator(empira MigraDoc 1.50.5147 \(www.migradoc.com\))
/Title(TrustID)
/Producer(PDFsharp 1.50.5147-gdi \(www.pdfsharp.com\))
>>
endobj
2 0 obj
<<
/Type/Catalog
/Pages 3 0 R
>>
endobj
3 0 obj
<<
/Type/Pages
/Count 3
/Kids[4 0 R 23 0 R 28 0 R]
>>
endobj
4 0 obj
<<
/Type/Page
/MediaBox[0 0 841.89 595.276]
/Parent 3 0 R
/Contents 5 0 R
/Resources
<<
/ProcSet [/PDF/Text/ImageB/ImageC/ImageI]
/ExtGState
<<
/GS0 6 0 R
/GS1 10 0 R
>>
/XObject
<<
/I0 9 0 R
>>
/Font
<<
/F0 14 0 R
/F1 18 0 R
/F2 22 0 R
>>
>>
/Group
<<
/CS/DeviceRGB
/S/Transparency
>>
>>
endobj
5 0 obj
<<
/Length 2094
/Filter/FlateDecode
>>
stream
x´┐¢´┐¢Y╦Ä´┐¢´┐¢´┐¢W´┐¢L:##´┐¢B´┐¢´┐¢´┐¢´┐¢Cw$´┐¢´┐¢~´┐¢´┐¢´┐¢╚¬´┐¢v´┐¢´┐¢´┐¢´┐¢3´┐¢*´┐¢8q"´┐¢´┐¢´┐¢´┐¢Io´┐¢´┐¢´┐¢´┐¢O´┐¢´┐¢´┐¢No?´┐¢qz´┐¢E´┐¢4'[^´┐¢´┐¢(Ì£W>´┐¢´┐¢9&´┐¢´┐¢´┐¢w█½´┐¢´┐¢´┐¢´┐¢´┐¢´┐¢█ôVA´┐¢´┐¢O´┐¢´┐¢
>´┐¢´┐¢´┐¢´┐¢´┐¢´┐¢~´┐¢S´┐¢´┐¢  ´┐¢´┐¢´┐¢█À_´┐¢K(_bt┬╣´┐¢´┐¢´┐¢!´┐¢´┐¢;9V&´┐¢G´┐¢´┐¢´┐¢;=´┐¢´┐¢´┐¢G´┐¢═┐]´┐¢E┌│Ì░´┐¢´┐¢[´┐¢´┐¢´┐¢fs´┐¢(p´┐¢╦Å´┐¢Z´┐¢´┐¢´┐¢>´┐¢´┐¢¤ô´┐¢.|´┐¢´┐¢´┐¢r´┐¢NQ ´┐¢Èû´┐¢´┐¢´┐¢)´┐¢d5´┐¢?´┐¢W´┐¢´┐¢´┐¢´┐¢´┐¢.:´┐¢$´┐¢´┐¢X´┐¢si´┐¢´┐¢´┐¢´┐¢´┐¢C´┐¢´┐¢´┐¢´┐¢Z5´┐¢j´┐¢U´┐¢Lr´┐¢qw3╚½3m)´┐¢>´┐¢´┐¢´┐¢Ðí´┐¢´┐¢´┐¢Yy´┐¢,/B´┐¢´┐¢´┐¢u´┐¢qW´┐¢ÐÅ´┐¢Ôö¿´┐¢E;´┐¢´┐¢ k´┐¢m=´┐¢´┐¢"´┐¢k´┐¢´┐¢´┐¢}´┐¢´┐¢m´┐¢´┐¢´┐¢\´┐¢*´┐¢y{´┐¢V=´┐¢%´┐¢8´┐¢´┐¢´┐¢k !D´┐¢´┐¢KGM´┐¢´┐¢´┐¢i´┐¢&´┐¢´┐¢
´┐¢´┐¢´┐¢´┐¢J*Y´¢ºX"6´┐¢|[j´┐¢´┐¢´┐¢´┐¢*´┐¢z)´┐¢´┐¢´┐¢>n&,w6´┐¢e´┐¢´┐¢5`Av´┐¢´┐¢´┐¢\ZD´┐¢e´┐¢I´┐¢´┐¢´┐¢´┐¢@´┐¢R ´┐¢a´┐¢´┐¢h2W´┐¢´┐¢´┐¢´┐¢´┐¢a´┐¢´┐¢´┐¢diT}T 3´┐¢,´┐¢il´┐¢´┐¢L´┐¢t}´┐¢E´┐¢´┐¢´┐¢v´┐¢´┐¢~f´┐¢R╚ôF0´┐¢´┐¢╔û
Su´┐¢´┐¢´┐¢36´┐¢´┐¢x´┐¢b´┐¢´┐¢´┐¢,´┐¢j´┐¢´┐¢v2R┘ÉÍô}W%´┐¢`F)´┐¢´┐¢c%´┐¢b´┐¢´┐¢´┐¢´┐¢)´┐¢6´┐¢/my$"5´┐¢\▄ƒ´┐¢T<´┐¢EN´┐¢´┐¢´┐¢´┐¢gXo7´┐¢´┐¢f´┐¢´┐¢
ng´┐¢╬É¦ñnD|b}´┐¢¦░P´┐¢´┐¢´┐¢$($´┐¢Èæ´┐¢´┐¢r1
´┐¢═Æ´┐¢`´┐¢´┐¢c´┐¢´┐¢h´┐¢ ](9´┐¢´┐¢´┐¢´┐¢´┐¢AßÜé´┐¢J>:´┐¢´┐¢u$`´┐¢E´┐¢´┐¢´┐¢´┐¢´┐¢´┐¢P´┐¢^0´┐¢´┐¢8h´┐¢´┐¢´┐¢8  g´┐¢´┐¢%zD´┐¢´┐¢´┐¢´┐¢7yRib´┐¢S´┐¢]´┐¢´┐¢´┐¢´┐¢´┐¢k´┐¢´┐¢A@´┐¢´┐¢´┐¢´┐¢-µ▒╣´┐¢´┐¢k´┐¢B´┐¢(:.´┐¢´┐¢)´┐¢po<´┐¢´┐¢Q´┐¢´┐¢0 ´┐¢´┐¢=*#Z´┐¢´┐¢´┐¢´┐¢´┐¢´┐¢´┐¢<Bs╩ö´┐¢_r   ´┐¢g´┐¢G´┐¢db´┐¢6GT´┐¢´┐¢´┐¢´┐¢,´┐¢┘ÿ%´┐¢zy´┐¢´┐¢UD´┐¢e´┐¢1l´┐¢´┐¢q╬è´┐¢´┐¢9p´┐¢j´┐¢´┐¢´┐¢´┐¢]D´┐¢a)´┐¢´┐¢j´┐¢´┐¢9,´┐¢_9´┐¢%´┐¢c&´┐¢´┐¢´┐¢"z´┐¢´┐¢S=$´┐¢´┐¢´┐¢\▄ñ35´┐¢´┐¢´┐¢i´┐¢9Q´┐¢▀¢´┐¢´┐¢~´┐¢´┐¢_´┐¢´┐¢.´┐¢þ║║´┐¢´┐¢´┐¢^¤¡y´┐¢´┐¢iC´┐¢´┐¢´┐¢´┐¢´┐¢O´┐¢ÌÀn´┐¢m* ´┐¢´┐¢´┐¢u´┐¢kk´┐¢#´┐¢R´┐¢´┐¢tÈï W´┐¢´┐¢G(Í«h´┐¢´┐¢´┐¢D´┐¢´┐¢k>khX´┐¢%@´┐¢J]p´┐¢#´┐¢1´┐¢´┐¢ÈÑ´┐¢O´┐¢f´┐¢´┐¢´┐¢´┐¢gl´┐¢´┐¢´┐¢T~LF´┐¢´┐¢yG´┐¢=´┐¢-´┐¢´┐¢´┐¢╔×3A─¬L´┐¢´┐¢Zx´┐¢Jf´┐¢v´┐¢´┐¢´┐¢´┐¢:´┐¢´┐¢FH´┐¢nW1{lX´┐¢´┐¢ZYlF´┐¢´┐¢tPm:´┐¢*y´┐¢´┐¢.a´┐¢═×=´┐¢.´┐¢´┐¢´┐¢ ÃÄ{q´┐¢v´┐¢Y´┐¢0LE´┐¢´┐¢
yÎ▓´┐¢´┐¢´┐¢´┐¢1TÎ¿´┐¢´┐¢k´┐¢RP´┐¢´┐¢w´┐¢;m´┐¢Da´┐¢A2´┐¢N´┐¢Xq´┐¢M´┐¢´┐¢´┐¢¤╝$´┐¢K´┐¢S´┐¢Ì╣9'´┐¢,U´┐¢├×´┐¢´┐¢"G´┐¢hWZ´┐¢´┐¢v─¼h´┐¢´┐¢EDr´┐¢`´┐¢Ae´┐¢ãÄ5$´┐¢´┐¢´┐¢Y´┐¢i´┐¢´┐¢e5´┐¢´┐¢(´┐¢8_
´┐¢2o´┐¢´┐¢´┐¢Pc´┐¢´┐¢) ´┐¢@´┐¢s´┐¢,2´┐¢">´┐¢´┐¢=)´┐¢´┐¢iM4j´┐¢´┐¢´┐¢O´┐¢´┐¢1
´┐¢´┐¢4´┐¢?´┐¢´┐¢R?{´┐¢´┐¢´┐¢´┐¢ÐÖCe´┐¢´┐¢µñ┐´┐¢_´┐¢´┐¢"}´┐¢´┐¢Ln´┐¢@TZK´┐¢´┐¢4´┐¢$´┐¢´┐¢"M´┐¢´┐¢´┐¢´┐¢JD´┐¢r$´┐¢´┐¢1G´┐¢´┐¢´┐¢´┐¢|´┐¢H2Îû´┐¢´┐¢´┐¢´┐¢´┐¢5G´┐¢´┐¢´┐¢@´┐¢´┐¢´┐¢´┐¢´┐¢´┐¢O{<D´┐¢´┐¢#´┐¢;K´┐¢M´┐¢´┐¢╩©´┐¢a8SD6s´┐¢´┐¢´┐¢´┐¢ ´┐¢G´┐¢´┐¢f ´┐¢´┐¢´┐¢´┐¢whw!"#´┐¢´┐¢´┐¢-´┐¢3A´┐¢´┐¢q´┐¢´┐¢´┐¢/´┐¢`´┐¢]g´┐¢qi´┐¢´┐¢5O}N´┐¢(´┐¢´┐¢0  ´┐¢1´┐¢´┐¢´┐¢´┐¢h´┐¢´┐¢
Q´┐¢6├Ç´┐¢kU´┐¢´┐¢´┐¢!´┐¢g/(´┐¢´┐¢uq4´┐¢n´┐¢n´┐¢~´┐¢╔©UR'4´┐¢´┐¢;P´┐¢aK´┐¢5ð¢´┐¢´┐¢´┐¢´┐¢´┐¢´┐¢ã¼R´┐¢´┐¢{´┐¢@7{´┐¢´┐¢t´┐¢¤╗J*´┐¢G´┐¢´┐¢´┐¢´┐¢´┐¢,:´┐¢´┐¢zB|´┐¢x´┐¢~-´┐¢´┐¢u´┐¢eH´┐¢vcwH"´┐¢c´┐¢´┐¢´┐¢   xC▄º´┐¢)O´┐¢´┐¢ny´┐¢yZEx´┐¢@e´┐¢´┐¢´┐¢´┐¢´┐¢´┐¢´┐¢}ÌÇ´┐¢´┐¢ZF0´┐¢fbT´┐¢´┐¢´┐¢´┐¢´┐¢.´┐¢Z(´┐¢´┐¢´┐¢´┐¢´┐¢´┐¢╬í<´┐¢O|W´┐¢t!´┐¢´┐¢X=´┐¢U´┐¢'4$´┐¢´┐¢U6´┐¢´┐¢ ´┐¢w7f´┐¢$t´┐¢R´┐¢´┐¢­ƒëëI9´┐¢%!´┐¢═ë`G´┐¢´┐¢´┐¢´┐¢´┐¢y
´┐¢b´┐¢´┐¢´┐¢´┐¢´┐¢<L'A!´┐¢w%h=´┐¢´┐¢´┐¢Bom´┐¢´┐¢q´┐¢´┐¢~uP7Vg(c8Gt>´┐¢}´┐¢´┐¢xg ´┐¢t´┐¢´┐¢5ð¡z´┐¢(@´┐¢;!´┐¢▄ò´┐¢j´┐¢═ºk2c&´┐¢k´┐¢z´┐¢´┐¢´┐¢´┐¢´┐¢´┐¢┬é´┐¢´┐¢´┐¢´┐¢´┐¢´┐¢)´┐¢=´┐¢V´┐¢´┐¢´┐¢´┐¢´┐¢´┐¢W\48´┐¢2´┐¢nG´┐¢´┐¢m´┐¢´┐¢ãü´┐¢Xs´┐¢´┐¢E*#´┐¢´┐¢#´┐¢Aj´┐¢´┐¢qJ╬┤c|w´┐¢´┐¢D´┐¢´┐¢´┐¢"7SËÿrL´┐¢u´┐¢1´┐¢´┐¢1´┐¢,]5´┐¢´┐¢´┐¢´┐¢ ´┐¢´┐¢´┐¢´┐¢´┐¢F´┐¢:´┐¢´┐¢\´┐¢´┐¢´┐¢$´┐¢m:q´┐¢6´┐¢´┐¢.}´┐¢  >0´┐¢´┐¢^╦À´┐¢HO´┐¢-´┐¢amO´┐¢´┐¢´┐¢E1´┐¢X╔äO´┐¢´┐¢´┐¢´┐¢´┐¢´┐¢´┐¢´┐¢/´┐¢<´┐¢´┐¢V}'´┐¢ ´┐¢^´┐¢´┐¢Qqz@5´┐¢´┐¢´┐¢d/y´┐¢´┐¢´┐¢Ãë3Zi´┐¢´┐¢ G=i[/9
´┐¢G_´┐¢C´┐¢´┐¢|´┐¢3´┐¢T´┐¢´┐¢´┐¢´┐¢/´┐¢´┐¢´┐¢ZV´┐¢´┐¢A´┐¢´┐¢´┐¢´┐¢´┐¢´┐¢b´┐¢BaÌ×´┐¢´┐¢´┐¢´┐¢<
```

if I try to save the response.data in a file on my disk it creates a 3 pages pdf with the correct some data showing on the PDF tab reader but the pages are blank

```
        const response = await axios
            .post('https://APIURL/exportPDF/', connectionJson)
        //console.log(((response.data).toString()))

        fs.writeFile('c:/temp/my.pdf', response.data, (err) => {
            //     if (err) throw err;
            console.log('The file has been saved!');
        });
    };
```

as I've been reading that the file might not be completely downloaded I've tried:

```
        const finishedDownload = util.promisify(stream.finished);
        const writer = fs.createWriteStream('c:/temp/myfile.pdf');
        let connectionJson = {
             "Username": "",
            "Password": "",
        }
        const response = await axios({
            method: 'post',
            url: 'https://APIURL/exportPDF/',
            responseType: 'stream',
            headers: connectionJson
        });
    
        response.data.pipe(writer);
        await finishedDownload(writer);
```

but writes a file 0bytes.

Comment: I you would need to [show some sort of attempt](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and any errors that you are getting to get any more help than links to [online](https://gist.github.com/adamgibbons/af2de54c011e68a7b85a) [guides](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-use-azcopy-blobs-upload).

Comment: I'll modify the question and add what I've tried, thanks

Comment: When you have a Buffer object, can you log out `theBuffer.toString()`? I guess this is `response.data.toString()` in your example.

Comment: Hi arfi, it doesn't print anything :(

Comment: but the docs say that returns a binary data stream that represents the PDF

Comment: hi KJ, I've updated the example

Comment: Hi KJ, thank you for your answers. I've tried this but I'm getting the same result as last comment "I am getting a blank PDF with the expected number of pages", but at least now the file saved is the correct size.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed it including responseEncoding:binary and option while writing the file
'binary'
Please read the comments in the code!

````
 async function axaios(idSession) {
        
        let connectionJson = {
            "DeviceId": "device-id",
            "SessionId": idSession,
            "ContainerId": contaierID,
        }
        //important! this option is needed
        let conf = {"responseType": "arraybuffer",
        "responseEncoding": "binary"}


        const response = await axios
            .post('https://APIULR/exportPDF/', connectionJson, conf)
        //console.log(response.data)

        
        //'binary' needed as option!
        await fs.writeFile('c:/temp/my.pdf', response.data, 'binary' , (err) => {
            if (err) throw err;
            console.log('The file has been saved!');
        });
    }
    ```

Thank you all for your suggestions! 
Thanks a lot KJ
````